# What to use? "vertical-align:top" or "vertical-align:text-top"

Tags: css, alignment, text-alignment

Are these two attribute does the same or is it got different usages?
`vertical-align:top` and `vertical-align:text-top`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference can be explained through `line-height` property.

[**MDN Source**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

> **text-top**
>       Aligns the top of the element with the top of the parent element's font.
>
> **top**
>       Align the top of the element and its descendants with the top of the entire line.

```css
.top {
  line-height: 5em;
}

.text-top {
  line-height: 5em;
}

.top span {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.text-top span {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">I am vertical-align: <span>top</span>
</div>
<div class="text-top">I am vertical-align: <span>text-top</span>
</div>
```

***Notice in the above example, the text-top is below the text when it is to be placed above it.***

It is because we have set **line-height: 5em**. `em` is relative to the font-size. And as per the definition the `text-top` will be aligned to the parent element(*.text-top*)'s baseline.

Answer (score 2):

> vertical-align:top :- This will align the top of element with the top of tallest element.
>
> vertical-align:text-top :- This will align the top of element the top of the parent element's font

Most of the scenarios is almost same , as you have same font and text in line. It will have different impact when your line has some other elements like image along with text, this scenario `text-top` will align your element with `tallest text` even if image is taller than text but `top` will align it with `top of image` or `who ever is tallest in line whether text or image`.

Answer (score 0):

Although, there is a very slight difference between these but both these attributes of the "vertical-align" property may come very handy while some text formatting. You may understand it this way that : *vertical-align* property is self descriptive that is helps in aligning elements ***vertically with respect to the line box height***. Now ***vertical-align:top*** , aligns the element’s top edge to the line box’s top edge. 
And whereas, the ***vertical-align:text-top*** aligns the element’s top edge to the line box’s text box top edge.